# Can we name ONLY the first 3 columns of a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I know how to re-name all columns of a data frame and I know how to re-name specific named columns of a data frame.  Now, I'm wondering if we can rename only the first 3 columns of a data frame.  When I export the data frame to a CSV file, it looks like this.

[image]

The name 'RCD' in the third column will be dynamically named, and the first 2 columns don't have names at all.  I'd like to do something like this.

```
grouped_and_summed.columns = ['Regulatory_Code', 'Line_Item','Call_Report_Schedule_Code']
```

Since it's expecting all columns to be named, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 74 elements, new values have 3 elements
```

Thanks for the tip Joe.  I ran your code, and now I'm getting this result.

[image]

Columns 3, 4, and 5 have been renamed, but not columns 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: You're trying to rename all 74 columns. Try only changing the first 3 columns: `grouped_and_summed.columns[:3] = ['Regulatory_Code', 'Line_Item','Call_Report_Schedule_Code']`

Comment: I don't think you can give a slice on the left hand side. you may have to give `.columns` and manage the slice on the right hand side

Comment: To use columns, you have to convert it to values first and then slice. My answer provides that option as well

Comment: Can you print grouped_and_summed.columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment from Joe already states, you are trying to replace all 74 columns. You need to replace specific columns or a subset. Try one of the below two options.

If the column names from your csv file results in

`'A', 'B', 'C'` then you can give this to replace the columns.

```
grouped_and_summed.rename(columns={'A':'Regulatory_Code','B':'Line_Item','C':'Call_Report_Schedule_Code'},inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you can give:

```
grouped_and_summed.columns = ['Regulatory_Code', 'Line_Item','Call_Report_Schedule_Code',*grouped_and_summed.columns[3:]]
```

This will create a list of all the columns. The first 3 will be your specific list, the rest will be columns from index 3 onwards.

An alternate way to do this will be:

```
grouped_and_summed.columns.values[:3] = ['Regulatory_Code', 'Line_Item','Call_Report_Schedule_Code']
```

Comment: Thanks Joe.  That sort of worked, but it named the wrong columns; it named 3, 4, and 5...not 1, 2, and 3.  I just updated my original post.  Please take a look and let me know what I did wrong.  This is after I reset the index on the DF.

Comment: Which of the 3 did you use? Try the first one with specific column names. Also please share the output of print(grouped_and_summed.columns)

Comment: Sorry about that!  The first two columns are actually indexes; I actually have two indexes in the data frame.  The first column of the data frame shows up as ColumnC when I export everything to a data frame.  All 3 of the samples you provided worked perfectly fine.  Thanks so much!!